# Is this an ok construction for a bathroom sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

I have a bathroom sink that is constantly clogged or running slow. I’ve cleaned out the P trap, removed the pop up drain stopper and it still ran slow. I bought a DIY snake and can’t get it past these 3 turns to see where the clog is. Any advice here? I’m wondering...
1. Is this set up correctly?
2. Any ideas on how I can set it up better?
3. Any ideas how to unclog this myself?

[image]

Comment: Remove the P-trap and try to snake it again.

Comment: That’s a lot of 90’s in a small space.

Answer (score 2):

As Kris said there are a lot of 90's , I fully agree with his comment, I would give an example from the electrical code that only 360 degrees of turns are allowed before the next junction box because of the resistance to pulling the wire increasing with each 90, the same thing happens with water pipes and a sharp 90 is impossible to get by more than 2 in many cases if long sweeps are used it may be possible but that's why you can't get the snake through.